# How can I get the UITableView scroll position so I can save it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is there any way to find out which `UITableViewCell` is at the top of the scroll window?

I'd like to get the current scroll position so that I can save it when the app exits.  When the app gets started I want to scroll to the position it was at when it last exited.

Comment: This can also be achieved as <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327230/swift-keep-tableview-data-position-after-reload/75837902#75837902>

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can easily grab the exact offset of the table view by looking at its `contentOffset` property. For the vertical scroll, look at:

```
tableView.contentOffset.y;
```

Comment: That's a CGPoint in the scroll view, I'm not sure how I can tell which UITableViewCell that corresponds to.

Comment: You don't need the cell if you use the offset; just set the offset when you re-enter the view. However, if you MUST know the cell at the top, just use:  [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];

Comment: using contentOffset works perfectly, it returns the scroll position exactly where it was when the app last quit.  Thanks!  I didn't need to know which cell it was after all.

Comment: for the c# user use this case:
tableView.ContentOffset.Y;

Answer (score 13):

The accepted solution only works if you know the size of all table view items. With auto sizing/estimated size that is not always true.

One alternative is to save the first visible item and scroll to it.

You can get the first visible item indexPath with:

```
savedIndex = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first
```

Then scroll to it by doing:

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(savedIndex, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can load in viewWillAppear and not viewDidLoad (tested iOS 9). ViewWillAppear is when view has finished layout - there is differences in the outcome.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *lightData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [lightData floatForKey:@"yValue"])];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *lightData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [lightData setFloat:self.tableView.contentOffset.y forKey:@"yValue"];
    [lightData synchronize];
}
```