# Remembering last scrollview position on UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift

i have a largely populated slide out TableView running in my app over 50+    cell row.When I scroll down to a specific cell and drill down to detailedviewcontrollers and return again the table is **scrolled all the way to the top**. I've had a look at the following questions that are similar

[How can I get the UITableView scroll position so I can save it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795900/how-can-i-get-the-uitableview-scroll-position-so-i-can-save-it)

[Setting scroll position in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413055/setting-scroll-position-in-uitableview)

[Remembering scroll position on UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843574/remembering-scroll-position-on-uitableview)

https://grokswift.com/programmatic-uitableview-scrolling/

I tried to workout the solution from the above link and answers but, still i have no luck so far.i am posting my tries as below.

**Method 1:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   self.myTableView.reloadData()
   self.myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -20), animated: false)
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   self.myTableView.reloadData()
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        let rowIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0)
        self.myTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(rowIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: false)

    })
}
```

**Method 3:**

```
func scrollToSelectedRow() {
  let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
  if let selectedRow:NSIndexPath = selectedRows?[0] {
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(selectedRow, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
  }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   self.myTableView.reloadData()
   func scrollToSelectedRow()
}
```

thanks in Advance...

Comment: I see you doing some scrolling when the view appears, but I don't see you saving any information about where we were scrolled to when the view disappears. If you don't save state, you can't restore it.

Comment: Also I would ask whether you are doing "return again" properly. In theory, there should be no information lost while you were out so there should be no need to scroll. I worry that you may in fact be creating a whole new table view, not returning to your old table view at all.