# UITableView lag when scrolled up after segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

After playing around with segue, I have found that my UITableView lags for unknown reasons after performing a segue. Please see video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPAVcvf9UcE
source code: http://pastebin.com/c62UZiNx

I have faced the problem after following the solution for this question:
[How can I get the UITableView scroll position so I can save it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795900/how-can-i-get-the-uitableview-scroll-position-so-i-can-save-it)

The only way I managed to fix this is by creating a CGPoint (like CGPointMake(0,20) ) rather than remembering it when the segue occurs.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailedPost" {
         if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailedPostVC {
             offset = tableView.contentOffset
             vc.num = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
         }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to fix the problem:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    offset = tableView.contentOffset
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.contentOffset = offset
}
```

Comment: Do you use estimate Height per chance?

Comment: No, I don't use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussed behavior is fixed since iOS 8.4, so the problem is relevent only to prior iOS versions.